# Setting the size of char datacolumn

Tags: .net, datatable, datacolumn

I would like add new column to my datatable. The column is of type char with length of 10.

DataColumn d = new DataColumn(fieldname, typeof(char));
dt.Columns.Add(d);

My Question is how do I add "size" to this column?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in C#, a `char` is **always** one character. Try this:

```
DataColumn d = new DataColumn(fieldname, typeof(string));
d.MaxLength = 10;
dt.Columns.Add(d);
```

Comment: Thanks. MaxLength only works on string datatype. I was trying char.

Comment: @Murali: That is correct, that MaxLength only works on the string datatype. Note that the C#, the `char` type is not the same thing as a database `char` column type. In C#, `char` is *always exactly one character*. If you want support for multiple characters in C#, you must use `string`.

Comment: @kbrimington I want to truncate extra characters when the character limit is exceeded(instead of throwing an error). Is there a way?

Comment: Surprised microsoft language creator cannot write new DataColumn() with MaxLength argument!  Isn't that what a constructor is for - a one-line param-values initation?